# How to load a value from an address stored in a register?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have following code:

```
[Reader]: $80820000 // Current position in ITL. (Item Table List)

LUI T4, @Reader
LW T5, @Reader(T4)  ; current pos in ITL.
```

([Reader] is my define. I use a MIPS assembler)

Basically 0x80820000 should contain the current position of the ITL. The ITL starts at 0x80800000 and throughout the code it will be added with 4 or 5 and so 0x80820000 will be updated later with 0x80800004, 0x80800008, etc. (I'm writing a script interpreter in asm)

So, now my problem is following: How would I now load the content of the address which is contained in T5 (for example, how would I load the content of 0x80800004 which is contained in T5)? I can't use registers in load instructions for base.

Comment: what MIPS assembler are you using? I've never seen '@Reader' as an operand in MIPS assembler.  To load the value at the address in `$t5` do `lw $s0,0($t5)`

Comment: @markgz Thank you, markgz. I wrote my own MIPS assembler which does that . :) It's called "CajeASM", you can check it out if you want. It's specially made for people who are modifying Nintendo 64 ROMs. Basically the "@Reader" tells my assembler to replace the define with the value I assigned to [Reader]: ValueHere. It also automatically recognizes upper and lower half of the value.